# Changing the value of the input range AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Range should change its value and position depending on the `param` and has not changed to change the `param`

**HTML:**

```
  <body  ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyRngCtrl">
      Param:{{param}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="rangeCtrl">
    <div>modelValue:{{modelValue}}</div>
      <input type="range" style="width: 300px;"
             min = "0"
             max = "300"
             step = "1"
             ng-change = "rangeChange()"
             ng-model = "modelValue">
    </div>
  </body>
```

**JS:**

```
app.controller('rangeCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.modelValue =  $scope.param;
    $scope.rangeChange = function() {
    }
});
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahoncharuk/ock204j6/)

Comment: Your example here does not represent your fiddle. Then, you are using two different controllers and then you are updating a value outside of the digest-cycle of angularjs.

Comment: @bash.d in the original problem, my controller
looks like that: [JSFibble](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahoncharuk/f84p3yd0/)

Comment: In the first example, the controller "MyRngCtrl" simply "simulates" value param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one more Answer using `$rootScope`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyRngCtrl', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  (function update() {
    $timeout(update, 5000);
    $rootScope.param = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) * 10 * 3);
  }());
});
app.controller('rangeCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  (function update() {
    $timeout(update, 5000);
    $scope.modelValue = $rootScope.param;
  }());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyRngCtrl">
    Param:{{param}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="rangeCtrl">
    <div>modelValue:{{modelValue}}</div>
    <input type="range" style="width: 300px;" min="0" max="300" step="1" ng-model="modelValue">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks great!
I went to the other side: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahoncharuk/0mp6e5o8/1/), and faced with the fact that I can not change "modelValue" at least for a while, until the value of "Param" not changed

Comment: if you reduce the period of "$ timeout" then there is the same problem will

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyRngCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  (function update() {
    $timeout(update, 5000);
    $scope.param = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) * 10 * 3);
    $scope.modelValue = $scope.param

  }());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyRngCtrl">
    Param:{{param}}

    <hr>

    <div>modelValue:{{param}}</div>
    <input type="range" style="width: 300px;" min="0" max="300" step="1" ng-change="rangeChange()" ng-model="modelValue">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This solution works, but your callback logic is tied to the timeout handler, this is not very good style.